# How can I import from a sibling package directory in python 3.8?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Since I've never had scripts big enough to need sub directories, I'm pretty new to packages and importing from different directories in python. Is importing from sibling and/or parent directories not allowed in python (3.8.6)?

In the following structure:

```
parent_dir/
parent_dir/__init__.py
parent_dir/parent.py
parent_dir/sub_dir1/__init__.py
parent_dir/sub_dir1/sub1.py
parent_dir/sub_dir2/__init__.py
parent_dir/sub_dir2/sub2.py
```

In the sub1.py file, I tried:

```
from sub_dir2 import sub2
```

I ended up getting the following:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sub_dir2'
```

If I try relative imports in the sub_dir1/**init**.py file:

```
from .import sub1
```

I get:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: One common problem is that all your code is fine, but you are trying to run the code from inside the package directory.

Comment: Hi there and welcome on StackOverflow. Questions regarding relative imports have been answered a couple of times already. When in `sub_dir1/__init__.py `: Sibling import:  `from .sub1  import $export`. Parent import: `from ..parent import $export`.

Comment: Relative imports are not a directory traversal mechanism.

Comment: Thanks everyone, running the scripts from outside the package worked, although I'm running into a slight problem with pylint while doing this. It says unable to import this package when I hover over the red squiggly lines, but when I run the code it works. How do I get rid of these and why are they showing up?